# Grails: Testing Optimistic Locking

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Using Grails 2.3.9

I am currently trying to test the optimistic locking in Grails. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/guide/single.html#locking) says,

> When you perform updates Hibernate will automatically check the
>   version property against the version column in the database and if
>   they differ will throw a StaleObjectException

In the integration test, I have something like:

```
def existingGroup = new Group("Group")
    .save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

def groupA = Group.get(existingGroup.id)
def groupB = Group.get(existingGroup.id)

groupA.name = "Group A"
groupA.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

groupB.name = "Group B"
groupB.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
```

The exception is, however, never thrown. So, I guess, I'm doing something wrong with the session/flushing. But all permutations (using flush and not) on that had no change. I would like to see that this exception is thrown.

I also tried resetting the version to 0, without success (groupB saved as usually).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `groupA` and `groupB` refer to the same managed (attached to the hibernate session) domain object.

If you print the versions after `groupA.save()` you can see that the version of `groupB` also changed.

You can create an optimistic locking error by creating a new transaction manually:

```
def groupA = Group.get(123)

Group.withNewTransaction {
  def groupB = Group.get(123)
  groupB.name = "Group B"
  groupB.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
}

groupA.name = "Group A"
groupA.save(failOnError: true, flush: true) // should fail
```

Here `groupB` is retrieved, modified and committed in another transaction. `groupA` still uses the old version so the save operation on `groupA` should fail.

Note that you have to use `withNewTransaction` and not `withTransaction`. With `withTransaction` the created transaction would participate in the transaction that is used for the integration test. So the behaviour would be the same as without any manual transaction block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `Group.get(123)` returns null. So, the test case is interrupted with the NullpointerException on `groupB.name = "Group B"`.

Comment: That is the case if no `Group` with id `123` exists. In this case the initial example you provided should fail with a `NullPointerException` too..

Comment: OK. I got it. I had the problem that the initial item was also created in the same transaction (I updated the code snippet), so inside the withNewTransaction-block that item wasn't visible.